# Create 2 sidebar panels stacked vertically, one with tabs, one without

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to have a sidebar panel with tabs, while it also has a shared element that doesn't change if you click the tabs.

Intuitively, this could be achieved if the sidebar panel could be split into 2 pieces where the upper has the tabsetPanel, and bottom the shared element, but I can't find anything that allows this. (e.g. `pageWithSidebar ( headerPanel(), sidebarPanel(tabsetPanel()),sidebarPanel(),mainPanel())`

Is this possible?

e.g. this gives me 2 sidebars next to each other and a main panel underneath the second:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("analysis-settings1",
               textInput("settings1",label = "set some options")),
      tabPanel("analysis-settings2",
               textInput("settings2",label = "Some other settings"))
    )),
  sidebarPanel(
    actionButton(inputId = "go", label="Go"),
               verbatimTextOutput("showsummarysettings")),



  mainPanel("..")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$go,  ignoreInit=TRUE, {

    output$showsummarysettings <- renderText({
      "analysis-settings1 include ... and analysis-settings2 include ..."
    })
  })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this doesn't solve your problem:

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    sidebarPanel(
        tabsetPanel(
            tabPanel("analysis-settings1",
                     textInput("settings1",label = "set some options")),
            tabPanel("analysis-settings2",
                     textInput("settings2",label = "Some other settings"))
        ),
        actionButton(inputId = "go", label="Go"),
        verbatimTextOutput("showsummarysettings")),



    mainPanel("..")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    observeEvent(input$go,  ignoreInit=TRUE, {

        output$showsummarysettings <- renderText({
            "analysis-settings1 include ... and analysis-settings2 include ..."
        })
    })

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```